# How to tell Emacs/TRAMP to use the local shell, instead the shell of remote machine?

Tags: tramp

I have the following function defined in my dot-Emacs:

```
(defun call-shell-refresh-browser ()
  ;; When pressing 'sf', save the content and refresh the browser
  (interactive)
    (save-buffer)
    (shell-command "python ~/Dropbox/Sys/Linux/chrome-refresh-back-emacs.py")))
```

It saves the buffer in Emacs, then switching to Chrome, reload the webpage and gets back to Emacs. This worked like a charm.

Until now, I use TRAMP to edit files on a remote machine. When I save it, and call the function `call-shell-refresh-browser`, it looks in the remote shell for the script `chrome-refresh-back-emacs.py` which don't exists on the remote machine.

How could I tell Emacs/Tramp to switch to the local shell on my machine, when editing a remote file? This is without terminating the current TRAMP session.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must change `default-directory` to be a local file name. Like this:

```
(let ((default-directory temporary-file-directory))
  (shell-command "python ~/Dropbox/Sys/Linux/chrome-refresh-back-emacs.py"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Will let you know if it turned out to be working tommorow!

Comment: it worked right out of the box! Thanks for that, it's appreciated!